# Axis2 and OpenSAML

Tags: apache-axis, saml

I'm trying to add SAML assertions to a SOAP web service that is built on the axis2 engine.  I'm having a little trouble wrapping my head around how the two would interact.  Could someone help point me in the right direction to add a SAML assertion to a response message from Axis2?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to include the rampart module as an extra module. The relevent section for configuring SAML support appears to be [here](http://ws.apache.org/rampart/setting-up-sts.html)

If you want more platform support then I'd recommend deploying your web service onto the [Web services application server](http://wso2.com/products/web-services-application-server/) produced by the authors of Axis2. It has GUI driven screens that assist in configuring the Rampart module.